# Sonata get Url of front end symfony

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I use Sonata as the administrator. How can I get the URL from Symfony.

With Symfony, it genrate URL in the view :
the view : url("/path")

With Sonata, it genrate URL in the view :
admin.generateObjectUrl('verified', object) }

In file Admin configure route:
[image]

Comment: Where in symfony do you want to get the url?

Comment: Assuming you mean in Twig, you generate routes the same in both places, using `{{ path('') }}` or `{{ url('') }}`. You can use `app/console router:debug` to help you find the route names after their configured in your Admin class.

Comment: from the view that call by the Sonata, I want to generate the url of the Symfony. I want to click a link at back-end ( Sonata) which point to Sonata.

Comment: Your question is not clear can you elaborate it more ?